# export multiple files in laravel excel

Tags: excel, laravel

**Code**

```
 public function collection()
    {
        $t= DB::table('sites')->select('site_code')->get();
        for($i=0 ; $i<count($t); $i++){
            $site=DB::table($t[$i]->site_code)->get();
        }
        return $site;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function siteexport()
    {
       return Excel::download(new sites(), 'download.xlsx');
    }
```

from this code I am downloading only the last file

Comment: are you using `Maatwebsite` library?

Comment: yes brother i am using maatwebsite

Comment: It's impossible to download multiple files in the same request. You can store() multiple files and later download them as a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue already listed on  [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel  github repository](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/279)

As per their response :

> It's impossible to download multiple files in the same request. You
>   can `store()` multiple files and later download them as a `zip` file

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/279